# How to refresh div using interval in php

Tags: php, jquery

Question: How can i auto refresh the div?? Below is my code but cannot to work. Any idea to solve this problem????

Below code is the main script that i want to auto refresh

```
<table id="auction-bidhist" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="">Bid Price</td>

                            <td class="">Bidder Name</td>

                            <td class="">Time &amp; Date</td>

                            <td class="">Bid Type</td>


                        </tr>

                        <?php
                            $querySelectBidHistory = "SELECT * FROM bidhistory INNER JOIN useraccount ON bidhistory.Bid_userId = useraccount.userID WHERE Bid_auctionItemId = :bid ORDER BY Bid_id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
                            $stmtSelectBidHistory = $conn->prepare($querySelectBidHistory);
                            $stmtSelectBidHistory->bindParam(':bid',$_GET['id']);
                            $stmtSelectBidHistory->execute();
                            $rowCountSelectBidHistory = $stmtSelectBidHistory->rowCount();

                            if($rowCountSelectBidHistory > 0){

                                while($rowSelectBidHistory = $stmtSelectBidHistory->fetch()){

                            ?>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['Bid_price']; ?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['userFullname']; ?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['Bid_time']; ?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['Bid_type']; ?></td>

                                    </tr>

                            <?php
                             }
                            }else{
                                    echo '  <tr>
                            <td class="text-center" colspan="4">No Bids as of Yet</td>
                        </tr>';
                            }
                            ?>




                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">The list will show last 10 bidder.</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Below is code to refresh

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
           setInterval(function() {
                 $("#auction-bidhist").load();
                }, 10000);
            });

</script>
```

any better solution to solve this problem???

Comment: load method requires a parameter, "the URL to be loaded".

Comment: if i put the URL , it will refresh whole page

Comment: You can load page fragments using jQuery.load(). http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 0):

1. create a targeting id
2. load the refreshed url.

javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("#targetId").load("auction-bidhist_File.php");
    }, 10000);
});
```

auction-bidhist_File.php includes

```
<table id="auction-bidhist" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="">Bid Price</td>

                            <td class="">Bidder Name</td>

                            <td class="">Time &amp; Date</td>

                            <td class="">Bid Type</td>


                        </tr>

                        <?php
                            $querySelectBidHistory = "SELECT * FROM bidhistory INNER JOIN useraccount ON bidhistory.Bid_userId = useraccount.userID WHERE Bid_auctionItemId = :bid ORDER BY Bid_id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
                            $stmtSelectBidHistory = $conn->prepare($querySelectBidHistory);
                            $stmtSelectBidHistory->bindParam(':bid',$_GET['id']);
                            $stmtSelectBidHistory->execute();
                            $rowCountSelectBidHistory = $stmtSelectBidHistory->rowCount();

                            if($rowCountSelectBidHistory > 0){

                                while($rowSelectBidHistory = $stmtSelectBidHistory->fetch()){

                            ?>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['Bid_price']; ?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['userFullname']; ?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['Bid_time']; ?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $rowSelectBidHistory['Bid_type']; ?></td>

                                    </tr>

                            <?php
                             }
                            }else{
                                    echo '  <tr>
                            <td class="text-center" colspan="4">No Bids as of Yet</td>
                        </tr>';
                            }
                            ?>




                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">The list will show last 10 bidder.</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

your actual html

```
<div id="targetId">
<?php include "auction-bidhist_File.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: or try passing some parameter in the loadurl, and give the condition with the passed parameter. but loading other page into the loadurl is the simplest way.